# How to set a Emblem to a File or Folder using terminal

Tags: linux, metadata, nautilus

I have used this command

`nautilus_file_info_add_emblem("NautilusFileInfo" new_file const char urgent)`

also

`gvfs -set -attribute -t stringv new_file metadata::emblems Urgent`

But these are not working.

Answer (score 2):

With this you can get the emblem:

```
 gvfs-info -a metadata::emblems <folder>
```

and with this you can change it:

```
gvfs-set-attribute -t stringv <folder> metadata::emblems <emblem>
```